# VBA convert custom date string to Date and Time

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

I have this date `TimeAndDateTZ = "2014-12-15T21:48:40Z"`
I'm trying to get two different variables from it:

Desired Output:

```
Date = "2014-12-15"  
Time24 = "21:48:40"  
Time12 = "09:48:40"
```

I know I could split() it on the "T" and replace() the "Z" but I want to know to do it properly.
I have tried to use CDATE and DateValue but I get an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Everything will be continue to be used as Strings, and yes `TimeAndDateTZ` is a string.

Edit #2:

(See my answer)

Comment: Is `TimeAndDateTZ` a string?

Comment: Do you actually need the values as dates or are you going to be dealing with them as string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
Sub dural()
    TimeAndDateTZ = "2014-12-15T21:48:40Z"
    ary = Split(Replace(TimeAndDateTZ, "Z", ""), "T")
    Datee = ary(0)
    Time24 = ary(1)
    Time12 = Split(CStr(TimeValue(Time24)), " ")(0)
    MsgBox Datee & vbCrLf & Time24 & vbCrLf & Time12
End Sub
```

Comment: That did work. But I also came up with an additional solution (see my second edit)

Answer (score 0):

`DateSerial()` and `TimeSerial()` would be good places to start.  See [This Tutorial](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=316:excel-vba-date-time-functions-year-month-week-day-functions&catid=79&Itemid=475) for more information.  Since your `TimeAndDateTZ` appears to be a string, you will need to extract the various parts of the date and time and add the components to the `DateSerial()` and `TimeSerial()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DateTest()
    Dim strDate As String
        strDate = "2014-12-15T21:48:40Z"
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        objRegExp.Global = True
        objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
        objRegExp.Pattern = "T[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}Z"
        If objRegExp.Test(strDate) Then entDate = objRegExp.Replace(strDate, "")
        objRegExp.Pattern = "[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}"
        If objRegExp.Test(strDate) Then entTime = objRegExp.Replace(strDate, "")
        entTime = Replace(entTime, "T", ""): entTime = Replace(entTime, "Z", "")
End Sub
```